# User flow after registration

Tags: python, django

I have the following user flow:

1) user registers.

2) user has a 'getting_started' page where he fills out some basic info and adds a picture.

3) user activates his email and logs in

After a user has finished filling out his info on the getting started page, if he goes back to the page `getting_started/`, I want the user to be redirected to his `home/`. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? (As a reference, similar to the LinkedIn or Facebook Sign Up flow).

The way that comes to mind for me is to set a global variable getting_started = 1 after the user fills out the `getting_started` page, and on the `getting_started` page, do --

```
if getting_started: 
    redirect to home/ 
else:
    ...(normal getting started view)...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it just the getting_started view/page that you want to redirect on? Don't think in terms of global variables, think in terms of database fields!

Once your user has signed up, they will be a registered user (if you are using djangos auth app) and they will have an entry in the database. Therefore you simply have to check to see if the user is registered already: if so, redirect, otherwise allow them to continue signing up.

You could simply put a check at the start of the getting_started view to see if the user has already signed up

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def getting_started_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_view'))
```

where **home_view** is in your urls.py:

```
url("...","someapp.views.viewname", name="home_view"),
...
```

(or you could hard code the redirect)

If you are looking for more complex redirects (maybe numerous pages that require a redirect to the home page) you should look at writing some **middleware**. This will allow you to intercept every request coming in, see if it's to a certain page, and redirect.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. One stipulation: if the user is on the getting_started page AND he clicks the authentication email in his link, I want the user to still be able to fill out the getting_started page. How would I ensure this?

Comment: You could add a field to the user profile (a BooleanField) that tracks whether or not this information has been filled or not. How are you saving this extra getting started data? Instead of using an extra field, you could just do a query on the extra data to see if it exists or not, and redirect accordingly, i.e. if GettingStartedData.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).exists() ...